# How can I get the id of div which is currently being hovered?

Tags: jquery, html

Suppose I have multiple div with same class but different id. How can I get the id of div which is being hovered by the user.

```
<div class='same_class' id='differnt_id_1'></div>
<div class='same_class' id='differnt_id_2'></div>
<div class='same_class' id='differnt_id_3'></div>
<div class='same_class' id='differnt_id_4'></div>
```

Let a user hover the div having id different_id_1 but we yet don't know the id of the element, we just know that user has just hovered an element. How can I get the id of the hovered element using jquery. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can user `this` reference inside the `hover` event handler.

```
$('.same_class').on('hover', function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

`$(this)` inside the `event` handler is the element on which the event occured.

Answer (score 4):

Add `hover` listener to all your div then `$(this)` pertains to the current element which trigers the listener.

```
$('.same_class').hover(function () {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `mouseenter` event and then use the `this` keyword to reference the element that raised the event and read its `id` property. Try this:

```
$('.same_class').mouseenter(function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bpcvy5k6/)

Note that you should use `mouseenter` *not* `hover` as `hover` will fire twice (once on enter, once on leave).